# looking for you tube video downloder app

Tags: windows, chrome, firefox

I am looking for a software, that can download video's from youtube like website.
And also it should be able to download flash video's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about flash videos *as they may contain active content* but a great tool is [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) which runs under python *it also can require one of FFMPEG/AVCONV for some operations.*

### Windows Installation Options:

**Python Installation**: Install as a part of [python](https://www.python.org/) with, *after installing python if you don't have it,* `pip install --upgrade youtube-dl`, *the homepage gives other methods for Linux & Mac users,* **or**

***Windows Only* Executable file**: [Download the pre-built exe](https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl.exe) and place it in a local directory or anywhere on your PATH other than `C:\Windows\System32` then run from the command line.

### Usage

There are lots of options but the simplest use is to find the video that you wish to download on YouTube, *or dozens of other services,* copy the video URL and from the command line run `youtube-dl` *URL* for it to go and get the video.

### Features

- Free, gratis & Open Source
- Windows executable or scripts that run on Linux & Mac.
- Options to throttle download speed
- Options to supply password if needed
- Options to specify downloaded video quality
- Options to specify downloaded video format &/or convert
- Options to include subtitle file(s)
- By default works faster than realtime, *(depending on your connection speed)*
- Currently 3gp, aac, flv, m4a, mp3, mp4, ogg, wav, webm are supported video download formats to select for download *Note that some videos may not be available in some formats from some URLs* You can use `youtube-dl --list-formats` *URL* to find out which formats are available.

Answer (score 0):

If you want web-only solution you can use Savefrom.net of Savemedia. No need to install (potentially unwanted) video downloader. I used both for downloading my favorite Youtube videos and there's almost no problem using them.